# How to set up cross-domain tracking in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

How to set up cross-domain tracking in GA4 right?

I followed official instructions: [[GA4] Set up cross-domain measurement](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en#zippy=)

I've added all the domains I need to the Date Stream Details - More Tagging Settings - Configure your Domains.

Added 'Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration' tag on the website using Google Tag Manager.

But now, when switching between domains, a lengthy parameter

> (smth like *"?_gl=1*1lop9ld*_ga*NDcxNTp2McYzKjE2LTcxMjQwKLv.*_ga_3JP1WO1NB3*MTYxNzEyNDA4Ny8xLjEuKOPxNzEyNLI5Ny40Nw.."*)

is added to the page address and the page does not open, a 404 error appears.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It sounds like your pages can't cope with unknown query parameters in the URL. Would any parameter cause the page to 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tony McCreath said, It might be a problem on the website's end on handling unexpected query parameters. I already faced this problem while working on a client website, and there was nothing that could be done on the Analytics side to fix the issue. You can test if that's the case by adding any random parameters at the end of the URL to see if the website still works.

The lengthy parameter that is added to the URL is the way Google uses to identify that a user is coming from another domain. It's basically an ID that will link the user from the previous domain to the current one.